# Crashing on setting up constraints for WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, wkwebview

Class containing WebView crashes on constraints. Here is the code:

```
class MyCustomCell: UICollectionViewCell, WKNavigationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet private var myImageView: UIImageView?
    private var myWebView: WKWebView?
    public var someProperty: SomeClass? { didSet { someLogic() } }

    func someLogic() {

        if myWebView == nil, let url = URL(string: path) {

            myWebView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect.zero, configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration.gifConfiguration())

            myWebView?.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
            myWebView?.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
            myWebView?.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
            myWebView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            myWebView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            myWebView?.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: frame.size.height, right: 0)
            myWebView?.navigationDelegate = self
            let request = URLRequest(url: url)
            myWebView?.load(request)
        }
    }

    // MARK: - WKNavigationDelegate

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {

        if imageView != nil {

            webView.alpha = 0
            webView.frame = contentView.frame
            webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            contentView.insertSubview(webView, aboveSubview: imageView!)
            contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: myImageView!, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
            contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: myImageView!, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
            contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: myImageView!, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
            contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: myImageView!, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
            contentView.setNeedsLayout()
            contentView.layoutIfNeeded()

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
                webView.alpha = 1
            }, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Here is the log:

> 2019-09-04 13:32:40.137078+0300 CultureTrip[27965:741645]
>   [LayoutConstraints] The view hierarchy is not prepared for the
>   constraint:   When added to a view,
>   the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view
>   itself). This will crash if the constraint needs to be resolved before
>   the view hierarchy is assembled. Break on
>   -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _viewHierarchyUnpreparedForConstraint:] to debug. 2019-09-04 13:32:40.138155+0300 CultureTrip[27965:741645] [LayoutConstraints]
>   View hierarchy unprepared for constraint.     Constraint:
>   
>     Container hierarchy:  ; layer =
>   >    | >    |    | ; layer = ; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {0, 0};
>   adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}>    |    |    | ; layer = >    |    |    |    | >
>   |    |    |    |    | >    |    |    |
>   |    |    | > layerID = 1 "drawing area root"
>   |    |    | >    |    |    | >  View not found in container hierarchy: >  That view's superview: > 2019-09-04 13:32:40.150305+0300 CultureTrip[27965:741645] Encountered an uncaught exception. All
>   Mixpanel instances were archived. 2019-09-04 13:32:40.150512+0300
>   CultureTrip[27965:741645] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to install constraint
>   on view.  Does the constraint reference something from outside the
>   subtree of the view?  That's illegal.
>   constraint: view:; layer = >'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001158d56fb **exceptionPreprocess + 331  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x000000011472aac5 objc_exception_throw + 48  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x00000001158d5555 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197     3   Foundation 
>   0x0000000111cb599f -[NSLayoutConstraint
>   _addToEngine:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 205     4   UIKitCore                           0x000000011d657bbd -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout)
>   _layoutEngine_didAddLayoutConstraint:roundingAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:]
>   + 447     5   UIKitCore                           0x000000011d657fb0 -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _tryToAddConstraintWithoutUpdatingConstraintsArray:roundingAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:]
>   + 30  6   UIKitCore                           0x000000011d658653 -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) nsli_addConstraint:] + 38  7   CultureTrip                         0x000000010d8262d2
>   $s11CultureTrip21ExploreTileMediumCellC7webView_9didFinishySo05WKWebH0C_So12WKNavigationCSgtF
>   + 1522    8   CultureTrip                         0x000000010d826bb1 $s11CultureTrip21ExploreTileMediumCellC7webView_9didFinishySo05WKWebH0C_So12WKNavigationCSgtFTo
>   + 81  9   WebKit                              0x0000000113e16438 _ZN6WebKit15NavigationState16NavigationClient19didFinishNavigationERNS_12WebPageProxyEPN3API10NavigationEPNS4_6ObjectE
>   + 92  10  WebKit                              0x0000000113e76f84 _ZN6WebKit12WebPageProxy21didFinishLoadForFrameEyyRKNS_8UserDataE + 784  11  WebKit                              0x0000000114076512
>   _ZN6WebKit12WebPageProxy17didReceiveMessageERN3IPC10ConnectionERNS1_7DecoderE
>   + 5980    12  WebKit                              0x0000000113ce32a6 _ZN3IPC18MessageReceiverMap15dispatchMessageERNS_10ConnectionERNS_7DecoderE
>   + 126     13  WebKit                              0x0000000113e99762 _ZN6WebKit15WebProcessProxy17didReceiveMessageERN3IPC10ConnectionERNS1_7DecoderE
>   + 24  14  WebKit                              0x0000000113cd61c8 _ZN3IPC10Connection15dispatchMessageENSt3__110unique_ptrINS_7DecoderENS1_14default_deleteIS3_EEEE
>   + 108     15  WebKit                              0x0000000113cd8bdd _ZN3IPC10Connection24dispatchIncomingMessagesEv + 717    16  JavaScriptCore                      0x000000011f0291f4
>   _ZN3WTF7RunLoop11performWorkEv + 228  17  JavaScriptCore                      0x000000011f029482 _ZN3WTF7RunLoop11performWorkEPv + 34     18 
>   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011583cbe1
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17   19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011583c463
>   __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 243   20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000115836b1f __CFRunLoopRun + 1231    21  CoreFoundation
>   0x0000000115836302 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 626     22  GraphicsServices
>   0x0000000118add2fe GSEventRunModal + 65   23  UIKitCore
>   0x000000011d260ba2 UIApplicationMain + 140    24  CultureTrip
>   0x000000010d74ab1b main + 75  25  libdyld.dylib
>   0x0000000116e6a541 start + 1  26  ???
>   0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1 )

Comment: As the crash says, you need to add the web view to the view hierarchy before you can add constraints. Check the relationship between your views. Where does `imageView` come from vs `myImageView`

Answer (score 0):

Add WkWebView to view hierarchy using `contentView.addSubView(myWebView)`
before this statement `contentView.insertSubview(webView, aboveSubview: imageView!)`

Comment: Nice solution @Sumeet

Comment: This does not fixes the crash

Comment: @Luda you tried adding `myWebView` at bottom level of hierarchy? if not try this `contentView.insertSubview(myWebView, at: 0)` then add constraints to imageView

Answer (score 0):

You are using `imageView` to add descendent constraint of `webView` inside `contentView`, so it break constraints due to `imageView` not found inside `contentView`. So please check where is `imageView` located and then apply constraints.

Comment: What do you mean where is it located?